# Google speech API bad voice recognition when using SOX

Tags: node.js, audio, voice-recognition, sox, google-speech-api

I am trying to create very simple voice recognition soft with node js. I have hooked up Google speech API and can send over correctly recorded .wav file and get back transcription and the recognition is very good (Recorded with Audacity)

BUT I have issues getting voice recognition "on the fly", like send the audio stream directly from mic to Gooegle speech API.

Here is my main method that records voice and sends over to google.

```
function recognize(encoding, sampleRateHertz, languageCode)
{

  const request = {
    config: {
      encoding: encoding,
      sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
      languageCode: languageCode
    },
    interimResults: true // If you want interim results, set this to true
  };


  // Imports the Google Cloud client library
  const Speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

  // Instantiates a client
  const speech = Speech();

  // Create a recognize stream
  const recognizeStream = speech.createRecognizeStream(request)
    .on('error', console.error)
    .on('data', (data) => process.stdout.write(data.results + ', '))


let fs = require('fs');
let Mic = require('node-microphone');
let mic = new Mic({ 'rate': '16000', 'channels': '1', 'debug': true, 'exitOnSilence': 6, 'bitwidth' : '16' });
let micStream = mic.startRecording();

micStream.pipe(recognizeStream);
micStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('test.wav') )
setTimeout(() => {
    //logger.info('stopped recording');
    console.log('stopped writing')
    mic.stopRecording();
}, 10000);
mic.on('info', (info) => {
    console.log('INFO ' + info);
});
mic.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
}
```

And the config data I pass to method

```
options({
    encoding: {
      alias: 'e',
      default: 'LINEAR16',
      global: true,
      requiresArg: true,
      type: 'string'
    },
    sampleRateHertz: {
      alias: 'r',
      default: 16000,
      global: true,
      requiresArg: true,
      type: 'number'
    },
    languageCode: {
      alias: 'l',
      default: 'en-US',
      global: true,
      requiresArg: true,
      type: 'string'
    }
  })
```

So I use 'node-microphone' for recording, I have Windows and SOX is installed. Send it over google. I dont get errors, but recognition is VERY bad. I get transcription on very easy words or phrases like "who", "food", "call". Mostly, if I speak normally nothing is returned.

I have a feeling, that something with encodng is wrong, or recording rate(Like, the record is "too fast" and google does not understand), but I dont see my error.

I also added file saving. When I open the file and listen to it, it sounds normal. When I send THIS file for recongition I get almost nothing back. So, there is something wrong with the way audio stream is recorded

EDIT : 
I am almost sure issues is in the SOX. All files recorded with some other program works much better.

Comment: Share the bad recorded file which does not work.

Comment: Here is saved file, that does not work : https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ly3toypnsute0l/test.wav?dl=0

Comment: The file returned by sox is 32-bit, google expects 16 bit. It might be a driver issue that it only returns 32-bit to sox. What is your sox version and your Windows version? What happens when you run this from command line: `sox -b 16 --endian little -c 1 -r 16000 -e signed-integer -t waveaudio default -p > test1.wav`

Comment: I have 64-bit version of Windows 10. SOX I downloaded from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/ It is a 32bit soft. And I did test out the command. You are right, it saved with 32 bit, even when specified to have 16

Comment: What is your sox version?

Comment: I have now v14.4.1, but the same result was with v14.4.2

Comment: Ok, try the following command `sox -t waveaudio default -b 16 --endian little -c 1 -r 16000 -e signed-integer -t wav - > test1.wav`